# How to extract the names of the layers from `sf::st_layers()`?

Tags: r, r-sf

I would like to extract the layer name of a shapefile with the R {sf} package.

I tried to extract informations from `sf::st_layers()`. i looked at the `sf::st_read()` but I wasn't able to see how it gets the layer name.

```r
st_layers(dsn = system.file("shapes/sids.shp", package = "spData") )
>> Driver: ESRI Shapefile 
>> Available layers:
>>  layer_name geometry_type features fields
>>    1       sids       Polygon      100     22
```

I tried to coerce to dataframes or tibbles but it is not possible:

```r
Error in as.data.frame.default(value, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"sf_layers"’ to a data.frame
```

I tried `st_layers(dsn = system.file("shapes/sids.shp", package = "spData") ) %>% .[["layer_name"]]` too, and got `NULL`

Answer (score 3):

The names of the layers are stored in the `name` column of the object returned by `st_layers`, as you can see analyzing its structure using `str`:

```r
str(st_layers(dsn = system.file("shapes/sids.shp", package = "spData")))

List of 5
 $ name    : chr "sids"
 $ geomtype:List of 1
  ..$ : chr "Polygon"
 $ driver  : chr "ESRI Shapefile"
 $ features: num 100
 $ fields  : num 22
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "sf_layers"
```

Therefore, using

```r
st_layers(dsn = system.file("shapes/sids.shp", package = "spData"))$name
```

should give you the name(s) of available layers.

Comment: Oh. That was not obvious to me. I didn't know that you can get a different column name in `str` than in the `head`. thanks :)